# What is a good technique to make Iced Tea?

Tags: tea

I've seen methods that call for different variations of boiling tea bags - throwing in ice cubes, soaking tea leaves overnight - refrigerate, slowly pouring the tea over a large chunk of ice after boiling loose leaf tea.  It seems as if they all make sense, but I would like to see a technique that works well consistently - what are the pros and cons of these techniques and what works for the different varieties of tea: Bags, Loose Tea, Tea Leaves?  I'm not concerned about levels of sugar ect. but the actual techniques involved to make the tea...

Comment: This is a rather obvious recipe request. Perhaps you could try some of the different variations you've found and ask for help if you encounter problems.

Comment: @hobodave - I disagree - he's asking about method, not recipe. He's not asking the ratio of tea to water, or how much sugar to add, etc.

Comment: @Michael: It's still entirely subjective, as evidenced by the different variations he admits to having seen. There really is not an objective answer. It's virtually indistinguishable from "What is a good _recipe_ for Iced Tea?" and "What is the best method for Iced Tea?". The answers to this question will be things like "I always do X", "My grandma's technique is X", etc.

Comment: @Michael @Atilla: Compare this to AtillaNYC's other question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/how-can-i-prevent-my-fruit-pie-from-being-runny This is a technique question that has an objective answer. If it were asked as "What is a good technique to make fruit pie?" it would be closed as well.

Comment: I've moved to reopen and edited the question to ask what the pros and cons of each of the listed techniques are, so it isn't asking "what is the best".

Comment: Ok, so there are several ways to make Iced Tea: Boil and let sit in the fridge; Simmer the Leaves at room temperature for 48 hours and then throw in the fridge; Boil and add Ice Cubes; Simmer the tea and then pour over the ice to limit the dissipation of flavor...It's not a recipe question and it's not subjective because one way isn't better than another, only preferred from different viewpoints....Sorry, fellas, thought some people would want to see different Techniques for a universally loved beverage...It's all good :>)

Comment: @AttilaNYC: Can you expand your question, and add part of the text you wrote in your last comment?

Comment: I still have to see a question on "Food and Cooking" that isn't at least a bit "subjective and argumentative". For the record of the closing-zealots, this is "food and cooking", not "calculus", it is usually not an exact science. Beside this, I see a lot of room for objective matter in this question, so I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Lorenzo, you need to stop using words like "zealot" here and trying to explain that cooking is a subjective field.  We know.  That doesn't mean *anything* goes here.  And as you can see, the system works; the question was expanded/improved and the community reopened it, with the result being a question that's much less ambiguous and more appropriate for SE.  Please try to keep the discussion civil; the debate here has been rational and amicable up until this point.

Comment: @Aaronut: ok, can you suggest a more politically correct synonym to indicate people that closes questions as fast as they can *before (and without) trying to expand/improve them* ? Because this question was closed well before any attempt of expansion/improvement.

Comment: @Lorenzo: I suggest (insist, actually) that you take such discussions to meta.  Comments should relate to the question at hand, not to the people who close them.

Comment: @Aaronut: while of course the place to discuss these question is meta, it is still useful (in my opinion at least) to have some in-context discussion.

Comment: @aaronut, @lorenzo, someone has asked a similar question in meta about a different question: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/q/674/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enjoy the fruity herbal teas as iced tea. I brew a cup and then pour it in a cup of ice. It is a sugar-free cool drink that tastes and smells great.

Answer (score 12):

The general method for iced tea is to boil water, and use double the tea for the amount of water and steep it for twice as long. Once steeped, add an equal amount of ice, and the ice will water down the tea as it melts and cools it down. If you want to sweeten with sugar, do it while the tea is hot.

This is the fast method, as you'll have iced tea as quickly as you can cool it (an hour or so in the fridge).

Alternately, you can steep the tea overnight in cold water in the fridge, using a normal tea:water ratio. This is the slow way. :-) If you want to sweeten the tea, make a simple syrup and add it (sugar won't dissolve very well in cold water).

Whether you use loose leaf or bags is really up to you. Tea purists will always say that loose leaf is better, but bags will work fine if you don't have a refined tea palette. Fruity teas often make really good iced tea, even if you're not a fan of fruity hot tea.

Comment: I don't like the "slow way" as I'm not confident in leaving the tea slowly cooling up to the room temperature, as bacteria colonies could start developing inside the tea (the water has been boiled, but it is not a sterile environment). About the "fast method", it really takes one hour to cool to fridge temperature? Which temperature is reached when all the ice has melted?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: the slow way involves cold water, in a fridge. You never boil the water, you simply add the tea to cold water and put it in the fridge.

Comment: The endless fascination with bacteria and toxins on cooking.se never ceases to amaze me.

Answer (score 10):

Growing up, we'd always make 'sun tea' -- you leave it in a warm place for ~8 hrs (we'd use a glass container in a south-facing window).  If you forgot about it, and left it overnight, it was foul -- you start extracting some of the more difficult-to-extract substances in the tea that are very bitter.  In the summer time, this could happen in under 16hrs.

So 48hrs seems a little *too* long to me, even if you were extracting at room temperature, unless that room was in a very cold climate.  I'm not sure off hand if there are issues with leaving tea out for long periods, as there'd be with food.

Now, after having lived for a bit in the US southeast, when they talk about tea, it's almost always 'sweet tea', which is always made hot, as you can't get that much sugar to dissolve in cold water.

Comment: I know southerners who will make sun tea and then add simple syrup.  Seemingly in equal parts sometimes...

Comment: made sun tea all the time when I was a kid in Florida. Mom would make it in the morning and it was ready in a few hours. Sun tea can harbor bacteria so the safer alternative is refrigerator tea. Takes longer

Comment: Sun tea always gave the tea a flavor I couldn't reproduce otherwise. (Hey, maybe it's the bacteria!) An easy favorite.

Comment: Sun tea is risky business (what with the bacteria growth).

Comment: @ashes999 : if you're using fresh chlorinated water, the risk is significantly reduced.  If you're using well water or other untreated water, then there's an increased (although still small) risk.  Also make sure to clean our your carafe between uses, don't just keep re-using it.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a little off from what you were originally looking for, but I believe you will find it relevant.  :-)

I'm a **lover of tea** - hot and iced.  As a kid my dad would make Sun Tea fairly often - and I always enjoyed it.  A couple years ago I decided I wanted to start making teas to have around the house as my "goto" iced drink of choice.

I experimented with many different methods - but had difficulty finding something that was easy to execute and still produced an excellent result.  Ultimately I discovered the [Hamilton Beach Electric Iced Tea Maker](http://amzn.to/fS7lLO) - and I've been happy as a clam since.

I've found that for straight black tea I prefer the tried and true Lipton's.  I use **4-6 bags at a time**, and **do not** load any ice into the pitcher (the direction suggest filling the container with ice). Instead I run **two full cycles of water** through the tea maker and end up with a full pitcher.  I add a little under 1/2 cup of sugar to sweeten the tea, and throw it in the fridge.  Serve over ice as needed, and I couldn't be happier!

I make 3-10 pitchers of this tea a week - and everyone (that likes tea at least) seems to love it.

This past summer I bought the same tea maker for my dad - which he said he'd never use.  Within a week he became completely dependent on it, and swears by it now - just like me.  :-D

**UPDATE (2016):** I wrote this quite awhile ago, and when I went back to that link, the only sellers of the Hamilton Beach Ice Tea Maker on Amazon were asking *over $100+ for it*.  That's a little insane; **I had paid only $30** for the ones I bought.  So if you end up purchasing an ice tea maker, you may want to consider another brand or model, as the model I used doesn't not seem to be available at a reasonable price.  Happy drinking!

Comment: I am intrigued...

Answer (score 3):

I find this to be a great technique for making iced tea:

1) Use double the amount of tea as you normally would for the water. I prefer simple black tea in bag form for iced tea. Loose tea seems a bit high end for iced tea.

2) Bring water close to but not boiling (seems to make the right amount of bitterness for my taste).

3) Steep tea for normal amount of time. Sweeten while hot (so sweetener dissolves) to taste

4) Here is my move... **pack a stainless steel cocktail shaker full of ice**. Pour hot tea into cocktail shaker and shake vigorously. You will be shocked how quickly the tea cools down.

5) Pack a tall pint glass full of ice. Pour tea from shaker into glass. Garnish with lemon. Sip. Think of easier times.

Answer (score 3):

I have never been a fan of melting ice into hot drinks to cool them off.  Maybe you've got some high quality ice machines with high turnover, but I know more often than not my ice carries a few tastes of its own along with it.  When it's just residual melting in an already cool drink it's not noticeable, but when you've melted a quart of it the freezer taste tends to add up.

I start off like most of the answers here (brewed hot, twice as strong).  Then, I use two big metal mixing bowls of roughly the same size: I put a bunch of ice in one of the bowls, put the other bowl on top of it, and then pour the hot tea into that top bowl.  The metal transfers the heat to the ice (and surroundings) very quickly.  After a few minutes, the top bowl will noticeably have sunk into the bottom bowl, indicating all the ice is now melted.  Depending on how much tea was made, it might be cool enough, or it might require replacing the melted ice with some fresh ice.

This way you don't have to worry about bacteria since it'll only take about ten minutes, and you don't have to make room in your fridge for a boiling hot kettle (and the subsequent heating up of nearby foods and such).

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember is that everyone has different taste in tea. The most important thing is to know what you want, especially as far as strength. With you goals and standards firmly in mind, experiment!

When experimenting, only change one thing at a time, and make everything as precisely consistent as you can.

As far as technique goes, we have found:

1. The water used can make a difference. I use filtered water, but some tea enthusiasts would say to use spring water. Tap water is an option, but only if it's drinkable (not hard or too heavily treated). The best drinking water I ever had was near Mount Shasta in northern California (glacier runoff) - I bet it would make great tea.
2. Use ice made from the same water, and make sure that it's reasonably fresh. Ice should add nothing to the flavor because when it does, it's always bad. If the ice is coming out bad, dump it and figure out why. Is it the water, trays, or freezer?
3. Use a glass container to mix and store the result. Make sure it's washed or at least thoroughly rinsed each time. We have a pitcher that we use just for iced tea, so it's easy for me to see if it has the right amount of water.
4. Steep time is critical. When you steep regular teas for longer than a few minutes, you get a stronger, more bitter flavor. Some people actually like their tea that way. I don't like mine that strong, so I stop steeping the tea after three to four minutes.
5. Different teas have different flavors. We use a blend with three different brands to get the flavor we want.

Answer (score 1):

you tend to want to get more flavour into your iced tea because adding ice cubes will dilute that flavour, but if your preperation includes boiling water, steeping tea, and then cooling (so not sun tea), don't try to get more intensity into the tea by steeping or boiling for longer than is recommended; use more tea instead. mainstream black tea blends like rose or lipton are made so that they won't go as horribly bitter as some darjeelings or greens will if you oversteep them, but they still won't taste as good oversteeped as they would otherwise.

I agree that sun tea and sweet tea are wonderful. for something different try an herbal like red zinger.

Answer (score 0):

I boil and seep cinnamon sticks let it cool and pour over ice not adding any sort of sweetner and it is very refreshing. I also found a lose leaf tea by rishi called blueberry roolbos which i brew and pour thru cheesecloth chill and pour over ice and it is good as well. I am seeking to cut down on sugar, however maybe once a week i will drink a glass of one of the above with kefir plain whole or lite and sweve sugar and it is really good. Cinnamon sticks are fair trade and/or simple organic. I normally use ground cinnamon in steel cut irish oatmeal. Again i am attempting to forego sweetening my food.

Comment: Always rinse the ice in the tray to avoid the top layer that leaves a film that floats on top of liquid in glass or cup. Hot or cold water will suffice.

Comment: Most teas will warn you of bitterness if over seeped. Candamon peppermint and cinnamon stick teas are a few that one can seep as long as one chooses and no bitterness is experienced that i have tasted anyway. Peppermint with you chose of sweetner and fresh lemon juice is a different taste and really good.

Comment: Boiling is just that boiling seeping is how long one allows the tea bag or loose leaves to remain in the water after turning the pot or other instrument off.

Comment: To make iced tea bring water to a rolling boil

Comment: 1. Bring water to a rolling boil.

Comment: Woha, hold your horses! Please don't add lots of comments, instead [edit] your original answer. Learn more about the principles when taking the [tour]  and browsing our [help].  Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers here, so I'm not gonna be repetitive. What I can recommend is to consider cold brewing as well. The advantage is that the tea will not taste bitter at all, while still have strong flavour. The downside is that you need it to be kept in the refrigerator for many hours before it's ready. You can try this video guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0Oyg_xWjZ4

Answer (score 0):

Place tea in clear 1 gal. jug. Set outside on east side of house at 7 to 8 am. In 30 to 45 min. Turn jug 180 degrees in sun. When color you wish is reached. remove to indoors. Add a little lemon or lime. Set in freezer. I 1 hour should be cool. Remove to refrigerator door. For your tea for the day. If more is needed in afternoon. Repeat on west side of house.